# I am facing an issue after removing an element from the DOM, I am not able to restore it

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am downloading my HTML UI code into a Word file using the **exportToWord** function. However, I want to remove the button text from the Word file while keeping it visible in the UI. Currently, I am using the following code to remove the button text from Word, but it also gets removes it from the UI after file download. I need to find a solution to restore the button text back in the UI below you can see the codesandBox link for reference.

My simple task is to remove the UI buttons in my Word file when I download it.

```
const removeChildElement = body.querySelectorAll(removeElement);
new DocumentFragment().append(...removeChildElement);
```

```
  exportToWord(element, filename = '', removeElement) {
    const body = document.getElementById(element);
    const removeChildElement = body.querySelectorAll(removeElement);
    new DocumentFragment().append(...removeChildElement);
    const header =
      "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML to Word Document</title></head><body>";

    const footer = '</body></html>';

    const html = header + body.innerHTML + footer;

    const blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
      type: 'application/msword',
    });

    // Specify link url
    const url = ` data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,  ${encodeURIComponent(
      html
    )}`;
    /* eslint-disable no-param-reassign */
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename ? `${filename}.doc` : 'document.doc';

    // Create download link element
    const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    if (navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
      // Create a link to the file
      downloadLink.href = url;

      // Setting the file name
      downloadLink.download = filename;

      // triggering the function
      downloadLink.click();
    }

    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
  },
```

```
<Grid
container
px={3}
pt={2}
rowSpacing={4}
component="div"
id="downloadDoc"
>
<Grid item xs={12}>
  <Box display="flex" alignItems="center">
    <Box flexGrow={1}>
      <Typography variant="h3">Dashboard</Typography>
    </Box>
    <Box display="flex" gap={2}>
      <Button
        id="removeElement"
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        title='Download Word'
        onClick={() => {
          utils.exportToWord('downloadDoc', 'exportToDoc', '#removeElement');
        }}
      >
        DOWNLOAD WORD
      </Button>
    </Box>
  </Box>
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={12} >
  <Typography variant="h4"> summery</Typography>
  <Box
    mt={2}
    display="flex"
    justifyContent="space-between"
    alignItems="center"
  >
    <Box>
      <Typography variant="subtitle2">
        {formikForm.values.summery}
      </Typography>
    </Box>
    <IconButton
      size="small"
      onClick={() => {
        seteditText('summery');
      }}
      title="Edit "
      color="primary"
    >
      <EditIcon />
    </IconButton>
  </Box>
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={12}>
  <Typography variant="h4">purpose and use</Typography>
  <Box
    mt={2}
    display="flex"
    justifyContent="space-between"
    alignItems="center"
  >
    <Box>
      <Typography variant="subtitle2">
        {formikForm.values.purpose}
      </Typography>
    </Box>
    <IconButton
      size="small"
      onClick={() => {
        seteditText('purpose');
      }}
      title="Edit "
      color="primary"
    >
      <EditIcon />
    </IconButton>
  </Box>
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={12}>
  <Typography variant="h4">performance data test</Typography>
  <Box
    mt={2}
    display="flex"
    justifyContent="space-between"
    alignItems="center"
  >
    <Box>
      <Typography variant="subtitle2">
        {formikForm.values.modelData}
      </Typography>
    </Box>
    <IconButton
      size="small"
      onClick={() => {
        seteditText('modelData');
      }}
      title="Edit"
      color="primary"
    >
      <EditIcon />
    </IconButton>
  </Box>
</Grid>

</Grid>
```

[CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-bash-6vz4qw)

Comment: if this question is not clear please let me know

Comment: You could just clone the body node, and then use that instead of deleting from body. eg. `const clone = document.body.cloneNode(true)`, now use `clone` instead of `body`.

Comment: Don't forget -> `header + clone.innerHTML + footer;`

Comment: Yeah check worked fine

Comment: for html2canvas  iframe what can I do to remove buttons because The script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages

Comment: because i am getting error on my pdf download Uncaught (in promise) Unable to find element in cloned iframe